# About the validity of an expansion result

Tags: estimation, asymptotics, distance

Suppose I have an expansion result: $sup_{p\in P,x\in X}|G_N(p,x)-g_N(p,x)|=O_p(a_N)$. Suppose now I have some (nonparametric) estimator for $p$ denoted by $\widehat{p}=\widehat{p}(x)\in P$ for any $x\in X$.

Do I have $|G_N(\widehat{p},x)-g_N(\widehat{p},x)|=O_p(a_N)$?

My guess is yes, as the  expansion result $sup_{p\in P,x\in X}|G_N(p,x)-g_N(p,x)|=O_p(a_N)$ holds uniformly over $P$, and we always have $\widehat{p}\in P$. Right?